# Choose linearly independent vectors from list

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a list of, let's say, five vectors, what is the most efficient way to find three vectors in the list such that the chosen vectors are linearly independent?

Comment: you may not find $3$ linearly independent vectors in your list.

Comment: Throw them into a matrix and row reduce.

Comment: Chris: How can I tell which vectors are the independent ones after I row reduce?

Comment: The linearly independent vectors will have a pivot column in them. I'll demonstrate below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have five vectors and you want to identify which ones are linearly independent. We can use a form of row reduction known as Gaussian Elimination. To do this we have to implement a series of row operations. The linearly independent vectors will have a pivot in each column (the first three).

\begin{bmatrix}
       1 & -1 & 2 & -1 & -1           \\[0.3em]
       2 & 1 & -2 & -2 & -2            \\[0.3em]
       -1 & 2 & 4 & 1 & 1              \\[0.3em]
       3 & 0 & 0  & -3 & -3
\end{bmatrix} $\\$
$R_{2}$ - $2R_{1}$ | $R_{3}$ + $R_{1}$ | $R_{4}$ - $3R_{1}$
\begin{bmatrix}
       1 & -1 & 2 & -1 & -1           \\[0.3em]
       0 & 3 & -6 & 0 & 0            \\[0.3em]
       0 & 1 & 6 & 0 & 0              \\[0.3em]
       0 & 3 & -6  & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} $\\$
$\frac{1}{3}$$R_{2}$ | swap $R_{3}$,$R_{4}$ | $\frac{1}{3}$$R_{3}$
\begin{bmatrix}
       1 & -1 & 2 & -1 & -1           \\[0.3em]
       0 & 1 & -2 & 0 & 0            \\[0.3em]
       0 & 1 & -2 & 0 & 0              \\[0.3em]
       0 & 1 & 6 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} $\\$
$R_{1}$ + $R_{2}$ | $R_{3}$ - $R_{2}$ | $R_{4}$ - $R_{2}$
\begin{bmatrix}
       1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & -1           \\[0.3em]
       0 & 1 & -2 & 0 & 0            \\[0.3em]
       0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0              \\[0.3em]
       0 & 0 & 8 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} $\\$
$\frac{1}{8}$$R_{4}$ | $R_{2}$ + $2R_{4}$

\begin{bmatrix}
       1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & -1           \\[0.3em]
       0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0            \\[0.3em]
       0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0              \\[0.3em]
       0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} $\\$
swap $R_{3}$, $R_{4}$
\begin{bmatrix}
       1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & -1           \\[0.3em]
       0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0            \\[0.3em]
       0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0              \\[0.3em]
       0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} $\\$